# Boost test linking

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, linker, boost-test

I want to use `Boost test` in my project.

I use cmake in my project so I wrote a simple `CMakeList.txt` for wrapping it:

```
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
file(GLOB_RECURSE UnitTests_sources tests/*.cpp)
add_executable(UnitTests
    ${UnitTests_sources}
)
enable_testing()
ADD_TEST (UnitTests UnitTests)
```

So, cmake works fine here. The trouble becomes during compiling:

> Linking CXX executable ../../bin/UnitTests
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In
>   function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the only file in **tests** folder (`LogManagerTest.cpp`):

```
#include "Utils/LogManager.hpp"
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE LogManager

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(LogManagerCase)
{
    BOOST_REQUIRE(true);
    /*LogManager manager;
    manager.Initialize();
    manager.Deinitialize();*/
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Just go to the [starter example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/intro.html) and then go to the [usage variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html). If you are not comfortable with linker options, etc... stick to the header only variant of Boost.Test. And yes: changing the order of the macros and includes **do have** an impact.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt so it will automatically generate a main() for you.
Also,

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE xxx
```

must be defined before you include unit_test.hpp.

You can find more information and options on:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html

Comment: It's defined in my cpp-file, isn't it? (your idea returned for me warning, that `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` is redefined).

Comment: It is defined only after you included <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>. So it didnt affect. You must define before.

Comment: I've found that while `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)`  resolves the problem on Linux, it breaks my build on WIndows(MinGW). If this happens to you, consider wrapping this line in IF(UNIX) ... ENDIF(UNIX).

Answer (score 8):

You need to compile with -lboost_unit_test_framework, boost generates the main for you if you use the `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` so you need to tell the makefile to look for that main. Then you can compile using the following:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE LogManager                                   
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(LogManagerCase)                                   
{                                                                      
    BOOST_REQUIRE(true);                                               
    /*LogManager manager;                                              
    manager.Initialize();                                              
    manager.Deinitialize();*/                                          
}                                                                      
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try moving

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
```

before your includes - it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once I made a stupid typo and also got this. And compiler was cheated.

Just as "#define BOOTS_TEST_MODULE DUMMY". Yes, I like boots :)